# Changing the datatype of an Array2 in a function's call in Rust

Tags: rust, rust-ndarray

I just started with Rust. I am trying the [ndarray crate](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/index.html), using a Array2 to load a matrix of integers I saved as .npy with type Int8.

This crate has a method for Array2 (although my problem will also happen with other methods, this is just an example) that is [.sum()](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.sum), which returns the sum of the elements of my matrix.

My matrix is 1000x1000, basically of 0's and 1's, and its sum is something like 400k. Now, because the matrix itself is i8, the method tries to return the sum as i8, which causes a overflow since the sum is greater than the range of i8.

I do know that just importing the matrix as another type of integer array will solve this, but I would like to try continuing to use i8 type. I do have a working code, with my Array2 saved as the variable arr:

```
{
        let arr = arr.map(|x| convert(x)) ;
        println!("{:?}", arr.sum());
}
```

```
fn convert(x: &i8) -> i32 {
    *x as i32
}
```

which is just casting the entire matrix to i32 before doing the sum, so I get the sum as i32. Also, the casted array goes out of scope after the block.

My first question: Is there some other workaround, perhaps a smarter one? I will be needing to get this sum many times, and I feel like casting the array everytime is not the most elegant thing to do. This also brings me to the next question: Is casting the entire Array2 like this slow/not a good thing? The current matrix is 1000x1000 but this is just a initial test, I will be using this to bigger matrices.

Comment: Why not copy the code of `sum()` and adjust it?

Comment: Also, consider packing the representation into bits. It will fit more in cache and can be counted faster.

Comment: And if the counting needs to go really fast, you can vectorize it using SIMD instructions.

Comment: I could copy the code for sum, but since I'm new to rust, I thought it had to exist more practical ways to do it. Also, note that I said that other methods also fall on the same problem, so I'd like to not do something like that for every method that raises this problem.
As for your other suggestions, I will look into both of them, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't want to use `map` here because it allocates a whole new array. Instead, just iterate and fold as you'd do for any other array:

```
let sum = arr.iter().fold(0, |acc, x| acc + (*x as i32));
```

Comment: Note that this will likely be less efficient than `sum()`, as LLVM cannot vectorize this and this also has bookkeeping needed for the iterator (`sum()` is also designed to help LLVM vectorize).

Comment: This helps, thanks! I'd still like to use the sum() method though, not only for what Chayim's commented, but because other methods will fail and a solution that uses the method would probably cover them all.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman this is less efficient than `sum` _when `sum` works on the original array,_ but it is vastly more efficient than `convert` + `sum`.

Comment: I'm also wondering if any speedup can be achieved by using [`as_slice_memory_order`](https://docs.rs/ndarray/latest/ndarray/struct.ArrayBase.html#method.as_slice_memory_order) to (maybe) get a plain old slice, which should be more likely to have its iteration be amenable to speedups?